# Python client side in chat

Tags: python, sockets, chat, raw-input

I have a problem while trying to build the client side of a chat. I just in the begining, this is my code:

```
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(("10.10.10.69",1234))
while True:
    message=raw_input("your message: ")
    if(message=="quit"):
        my_socket.close()
        break
    my_socket.send(message)
    data=my_socket.recv(1024)
    print "message from server:" , data
```

The problem is the `raw_input`. When a user sends a message the other users are stacked on the `raw_input` so only when they sends a message too they get the new messages.

How can I fix it (without using threads)?

Comment: Which OS do you use? In Unix, you can use `select.select`. In Windows, you should use thread.   Now you have another problem: you input get messed if you get message in the middle of typing.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu.
The other problems I will fix later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented, use [`select.select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) if your chat client is running in Unix.

For example:

```
import socket
import sys
import select

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(("10.10.10.69",1234))
sys.stdout.write('your message: ')
sys.stdout.flush()
while True:
    r, w, x = select.select([sys.stdin, my_socket], [], [])
    if not r:
        continue
    if r[0] is sys.stdin:
        message = raw_input()
        if message == "quit":
            my_socket.close()
            break
        my_socket.send(message)
        sys.stdout.write('your message: ')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        data = my_socket.recv(1024)
        print "message from server:" , data
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it on windows? using select.select?
I dont want to use theards.

Comment: @Nityuiop18, You can't use `select.select` (for this problem) on windows because it does only work with sockets on Windows.

Comment: The implementation on windows may not be as clean but I think u can use 2 threads to achieve the same effect. One will only wait on user input and send to server, the other receives from server

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` holds up the thread it's in, so you can't retrieve messages in the same thread while waiting for it. Thus, I recommend using 2 threads, one which receives new messages (say every ten seconds) and one which sends messages (using code similar to the existing code).

If you're not committed to `raw_input` and are really against threads, you might want to look into the [select module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-select.html).

Comment: I want to do it without using theards

Comment: I don't think that's possible if you're using `raw_input`.

Comment: I can do it without raw_input?

Comment: look into the [select module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-select.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are suggestions to use select() for stdin, but seems they aren't fixing the main problem. With select, imagine the local user is entering a line, and in a middle of this process your program outputs another user message, and, the editing of local input will be screwed. Either you don't allow to show new messages during entering the current one (why?) or screen is messed up. If you do this in a terminal, you should go using [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) or some more powerful tool; with curses you can at least split input and output into different screen areas. Of course, a graphics library (like [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)) is even more generally suitable for a user interface, if it's allowed in your case.